# Integral bee question.

Tags: integration

While I was preparing for an integrals contest, I had a doubt about the following integral, I tried several substitutions but nothing worked.I would appreciate your support for this beautiful integral.
$$ \int\limits_{0}^{1/2} \cos(1-\cos(1-\cos(...(1-\cos(x))...) \ \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: May you show what the several substitutions were?

Comment: Yes, one of the most common tricks I've seen is to make the integration bounds change to be -a and a

Comment: For $-1 < u < 1, ~1 - u + u^2 - u^3 + \cdots - \cdots$ is equal to $~\dfrac{1}{\color{red}{\text{what}}} ~?$

Comment: Now posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [Integral $\int\limits_{0}^{1/2} \cos(1-\cos(1-\cos(...(1-\cos(x))...) \ \mathrm{d}x$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/443515)

Answer (score 3):

Compute the limit of the integrand. Use the fact that $1 - \cos(u) = 2\sin^2(u/2) \leq u^2/2$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How could that help me to solve the problem?

Comment: @Gonçalo: no, that can't be right, at least for any given finite compositional depth.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Consider
$$t_1=1-\cos(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad t_n=1-\cos(t_{n-1})$$ and compose Taylor series limited to the first term. Then, the inegrand will successively be
$$\left\{\frac{x^2}{2},\frac{x^4}{8},\frac{x^8}{128},\cdots\right\}$$

Comment: I don't understand